# Arms distorted with Auto Rig Pro export to UE4

Tags: scale, unreal-engine, auto-rig-pro

To anyone who can help.
I used Auto Rig Pro to rig my character in Blender 2.8 and exported it into UE4.
The transfer went fine but the arms on the imported Blender character are shrunken down into the shoulders.
Also the shoulder width is decreased as well.

Thank you for your time and attention.
[image]

Comment: I use Auto Rig Pro, but I've never exported a rig with it, so I can't advise. I can tell you, though, that It's hard to get questions about ARP answered here because it's a paid addon, and so probably almost nobody here uses it. In the interest of getting you a response that will actually help, and in a timely manner, I would suggest sending Artell an email.

Comment: Appreciate the tip.
I will email him directly.